# reduced suspension and intersection and union of subspaces.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose we have a spectrum $E$ (in the sense of algebraic topology) and a  family of subspectra $(E^i)_{i \in I}$. I want to show that the intersection and the union of this family (componentwise taken with the subspace topology) is again a subspectrum. If the structure map of $E$ is $\sigma$, then it is to show, that for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $\sigma_n \left(  \Sigma \bigcap_{i \in I} E_n^i \right) \subseteq \bigcap_{i \in I} E_{n+1}^i$ and $\sigma_n \left( \Sigma \bigcup_{i \in I} E_n^i \right) \subseteq \sigma_n \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} E^i_{n+1} \right)$.

One way to show this would be to show that the reduced suspension preserves inclusions or unions, or that at least $\Sigma \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \subseteq \bigcup_{i \in I} \Sigma X_i$ (and similar for the intersection) hold for some subspaces of a bigger space. Are there any formulas of the reduced suspension with intersection and union?

Comment: Do you mean "union" instead of "unit"?

Comment: Yes, you are right